Are the Turing degrees on Cantor exactly the same on Baire?
Background:
As far as I know, the Turing degrees are usually defined (considering sets of naturals) on the Cantor space $2^\omega$ as the equivalence classes induced by the Turing reducibility $\le_T$. That is for $X \in 2^\omega$:
$$
\deg_T^{2^\omega}(X) := \{ Y \in 2^\omega \mid Y \equiv_T X \} = \{ Y \in 2^\omega \mid \exists e_1, e_2 \in \omega( Y = \Phi_{e_1}(X) \land X = \Phi_{e_2}(Y) )\}
$$
where $\{\Phi_e\}_{e \in \omega}$ is an enumeration of the Turing functionals (thus $\exists e_1 \in \omega (Y = \Phi_{e_1}(X))$ means that $Y$ is $X$-computable).
Similarly (if we consider functions of naturals) on the Baire space $\omega^\omega$, we can also define the Turing reducibility and hence the Turing degree for $x \in \omega^\omega$ is:
$$
\deg_T^{\omega^\omega}(x) := \{ y \in \omega^\omega \mid y \equiv_T x \} = \{ y \in 2^\omega \mid \exists e_1, e_2 \in \omega( y = \Phi_{e_1}(x) \land x = \Phi_{e_2}(y) )\}
$$
My question: For every degree defined on Cantor, is there another degree "equivalent" to it on Baire? And vice versa?
But what do I mean by "equivalent"? I mean that for every $X \in 2^\omega$ exists $x \in \omega^\omega$ such that
$$
\forall Y \in \deg_T^{2^\omega}(X) \exists y \in \deg_T^{\omega^\omega}(x) (Y \equiv_T y) \text{ and } \forall y \in \deg_T^{\omega^\omega}(x) \exists Y \in \deg_T^{2^\omega}(X) (Y \equiv_T y)
$$
Of course this requires introducing the concept of computable function from the Cantor to the Baire spaces, but it should be straightforward. Moreover, a positive answer to these questions should answer to the question in the title.
My attempt: The first question is trivial since we can just consider the same element (since we can consider a set to be the same with its characteristic function). But if I start from a degree in Baire, it is not completely clear to me which element of Cantor we should consider. I think the following should work: given $x = x_0x_1x_2\dots$ we consider
$
X = 1\underbrace{0 \dots 0}_{x_0+1}1\underbrace{0 \dots 0}_{x_1+1}1\underbrace{0 \dots 0}_{x_2+1}1\underbrace{0 \dots 0}_{x_3+1}1\dots
$. But I am not sure about how to prove it formally.
Another question: Moreover, following this solution one can observe that we have defined two functions to solve the two problems. The first is the identity $\operatorname{id}: 2^\omega \to \omega^\omega$ and is therefore computable, what can we say about the latter? Is this second function, that we can call $\operatorname{code}: \omega^\omega \to 2^\omega$, also computable?

It seems to me that you have the answer already, so I'm not really sure what your doubt is. If you're confident that it makes sense to have a computable function between the Cantor and the Baire space, then every $X\in 2^\omega$ is equivalent to $X\in \omega^\omega$, and every $x\in \omega^\omega$ can be computably mapped to $\bar X = 10^{x_0}10^{x_1}\dots$ as you suggested. An alternative could be mapping $x$ to the (characteristic function of the) set $\{ \langle n,x_n\rangle : n \in\omega\}$ (where $\langle\cdot \rangle:\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$ is a computable bijection).  To show that $x \equiv_T \bar X$, $\bar X \le_T x$ is trivial (this is how we build $\bar X$), while $x\le_T \bar X$ follows from the fact that, to know $x_n$, we just need to count the number of $0$s between the $n$-th and the $(n+1)$-th $1$ (which is clearly computable). Then, if you take any $Y\equiv_T X$ and any $y\equiv_T x$, $Y\equiv_T y$ follows by transitivity (or, if you prefer, by composing the Turing reductions).

Is this kind of description of the computable procedure for the reduction $x \le_T \overline{X}$  considered formal? What I had in mind with the word "formally" was to exibihit a Turing Machine or a computable function that works with $\overline{X}$ as an oracle (I asked because it seemed a bit cumbersome to make).
About my second question: I know that makes sense to talk about computability between Cantor and Baire as recursively presented metric spaces.
But using the representation functions for these kind of spaces is $\operatorname{code}$ computable?

I guess you can consider it "formal enough" :) nobody really writes fully formal proofs, they would be utterly unreadable. Writing an explicit Turing machine that does the job would be a more precise way to this, but indeed that's just a tedious exercise. Can you think of a C program (with infinite memory) that does it? They are equivalent to Turing machines, so that would be enough.

For the other question, no need to call in more complicated stuff like computably presented metric spaces. Ultimately, it boils down to how does your TM looks like exactly: if you are allowed to work with natural numbers directly then it should be easy. If your TM has a binary alphabet, then you need to code natural numbers anyway. For these kind of models, usually you say something like this: "$f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ is computable if there is a TM st, when executed with input $0^n1$ produces $0^{f(n)}1$". So, if you want, this kind of coding of $\mathbb{N}$ is computable "by definition".

@Manilo Yes I can think it as a C program. Just a curiosity: the fact that C programs are equivalent to TMs is due to the Church-Turing thesis, or is it actually a provable fact? For the other question: Maybe I misunderstood your answer, but I wasn't talking about the functions that do the Turing-riduction. I was talking about the functions $\operatorname{code}: \omega^\omega \to 2^\omega$ and $\operatorname{id}: 2^\omega \to \omega^\omega$.

It is a provable fact. Or better, the equivalence may depend on the exact specification of the C language you have in mind (there may be some limitation of C that prevent it from simulating every TM, but I'm not expert enough to comment on that), but you can certainly turn a C program into a TM. See eg Odifreddi, Classical Recursion Theory, Ch. 1, for equivalent models of computation. Church-Turing thesis essentially says that being computable by a TM truly captures the intuitive idea of computable, but if you have a C program this is way more than just being intuitively computable.

For the second question: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking. Are you asking whether/why the function $\mathrm{code}:\omega^\omega\to2^\omega$ is computable?

Okay, thank you! Yes this is my second question. In particular I'm not sure if the only way to prove it is to consider the representations of Cantor and Baire as recursively presented metric spaces, or there is a more obvious (but still equivalent) way.

Usually you call $F:\omega^\omega \to \omega^\omega$ (or $2^\omega\to 2^\omega$, the details are not super important) computable if there is a monotone computable $f:\omega^{<\omega} \to \omega^{<\omega}$ ($\omega^{<\omega}$ denotes finite strings of natural numbers) s.t. for every $x\in\omega^\omega$ and $m$ there is $n$ such that $|f(x[n])|\ge m$ and $\lim_n f(x[n]) = F(x)$. In other words, you can computably get arbitrarily long prefixes of the solution given sufficiently long prefixes of the input. With this definition, it shouldn't be hard to check that $\mathrm{code}$ is computable.

Yes thank you! I was aware of this definition (which I read for the first time in your Phd thesis :)), but I wasn't sure if it works in the same way when the domain and the codomain aren't both the Baire space. Thanks for your answers and your patience.
